# Using Baidu Map tiles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, tiles, china, baidu-maps

I am currently studying the Chinese city of Shenhzen and would like to use Baidu map tiles in QGIS. I tried using this XYZ url:

> http://online1.map.bdimg.com/onlinelabel/?qt=tile&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7B-y%7D&z=%7Bz%7D&styles=pl&scaler=1&p=1

But this does not work anymore. I am trying to find accurate road and building footprint data for the area and I see that Baidu maps is the only service that does so without distorting the view.

If you have any suggestions or advice it would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this one is a correct URL: [http://online1.map.bdimg.com/onlinelabel/?qt=tile&x={x}&y={-y}&z={z}&styles=pl&scaler=1&p=1](http://online1.map.bdimg.com/onlinelabel/?qt=tile&x={x}&y={-y}&z={z}&styles=pl&scaler=1&p=1) ?

Comment: This thread look the same to me : https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/315706/99589

Comment: I know it looks the same, but that one is outdated or doesn't work for me

Comment: Taras, the URL you shared also doesn't show anything when I create a new connection in QGIS